# How move add to cart button below product images in product page magento2.2.4

Tags: magento2, addtocart, product-details

Try every possibility. it's not working.

```
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.media" after="product.media"
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.media" after="-"/>
```

Comment: may be you are trying on wrong xml, which file and where you are doing the change?

Answer (score 0):

Please instead of `product.info.addtocart` use `addtocart`. Please check [this link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.4/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml#L72).